# "How to solve it" for theory builders?

Tags: education

Gowers has written a paper where he distinguishes between [two cultures of mathematics](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/2cultures.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj4jYe3y4_kAhXgTxUIHbIJBXAQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2gizQDX1knXJGDJ29ju9z3): *theory builders* and *problem solvers*.

There are many textbooks on "how to solve mathematical problems", or "how to prove things", such as Pólya's books, e.g. [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It). I have looked at a few of them in the past, and so far as I can remember, they tend to have a "*problem solver*" perspective.

**Are there such "how to do mathematics" books that take a *theory-builder* perspective?**

Comment: Grothendieck's story about how to open a nut might be an example of what you're talking about. Some of the answers here might be interesting: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/grothendiecks-approach-to-solving-problems

Comment: I don't know if it's at all what you're asking for, but you might like Thurston's essay "[On Proof and Progress in Mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9404236)".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what are you looking for.

But maybe reading about history, philosophy and the biography of the mainly theory-builder of math can help you to understand how they worked.